# wx.combobox managed by sizer?

Tags: wxpython

I've been looking around the web and all the examples I've seen have a given pos=(x,y) attribute for a wx.ComboBox or wx.Choice. However I need to let the position of the combobox (or an equivalent Widget) be managed by my sizer. Doing:

```
    itemSelect = wx.ComboBox(self, choices = list, style = wx.CB_DROPDOWN)      
    itemSelect.AppendItems(strings=list)
    itemSelect.Select(n=0)
    itemSizer.Add(itemSelect, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

This creates the combobox but it is displayed in wrong positions. Should this work or is it another way to add it to the sizer ?

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: That bit of code will produce completely different results depending on the type / orientation of the sizer, and the `proportion` of any other widgets you have added to it.  We have no way of knowing how it looks now or how you want it to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work, assuming there is more code you aren't showing us. Are you calling `self.SetSizer(itemSizer)` to associate the sizer with you container widget?

Comment: Something of the sort was the problem. Problem was that I was using a panel that had panel.SetSizer(itemSizer) but I was creating  the combobox with self(the frame) as parent and my positioning got all screwed up.